# Better way to write the following program in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm writing a function that reduce free words. One can consider it as the following algorithm:

The idea is to cancel items in the list, if they are negative of each other and adjacent to each other. Apply it repeatedly until there is no more to cancel. For example
[-2,1,-1,2,3] -> [-2,2,3]->[3]

I wrote the following code. It doesn't seem elegant. It uses head, tail many times, and there are total of 3 patterns for this function's input, it be nice if it can be reduced to 2.
I want to know if there are more elegant ways to write it in Haskell. I suspect I can use fold for this, but I don't see how to do it naturally.

```
freeReduce []  = []
freeReduce [x] = [x]
freeReduce (x:xs)
  | x == -(head xs) = freeReduce (tail xs)
  | otherwise       = if' (rest == [])
                          [x]
                          (if' (x == - (head rest)) (tail rest) (x:rest))
  where rest = freeReduce xs
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is the clearest I can make it:

```
freeReduce []       = []
freeReduce (x : xs) = case freeReduce xs of
                           y : ys | y == -x ->     ys
                           ys               -> x : ys
```

Or equivalently:

```
freeReduce = foldr f []
  where f x (y : ys) | y == -x =     ys
        f x ys                 = x : ys
```

(Both untested.)

It seems that `freeReduce` is inherently strict.

(My original, incorrect attempt:

```
freeReduce (x : y : rest) | x == -y =     freeReduce rest
freeReduce (x : rest)               = x : freeReduce rest
freeReduce []                       =     []
```

(Untested.))

Comment: I like the approach. However, `freeReduce [-2,1,-1,2,3]` yields `[-2,2,3]` (just tested it), which is not the desired result.

Comment: Good spot. I have amended my answer.

Comment: I like your second definition.  Your function `f` has a clearly defined meaning: given a single letter `x` and a reduced word `xs`, it returns the reduced word for the product of `x` and `xs`.  I would name `f` as something like `consReduce`.

Answer (score 12):

You need access to elements before and after the current inspection point, so something like this:

```
freeReduce :: (Num a) => [a] -> [a]
freeReduce = red []
  where red xs         []           = reverse xs
        red (x:xs) (y:ys) | x == -y = red    xs  ys
        red xs     (y:ys)           = red (y:xs) ys
```

You move elements from the second list to the first list and only ever compare the top of those list.  So it's one sweep over the list, and then reversing it back at the end.

Comment: I thought - use a list as a stack, pushing new numbers on the list, popping when they cancel. Your solution can also be thought of as a stack, perticularly if you replace the variable `xs` with `stack` and `x` with `peek`.

Answer (score 6):

Wouldn't be the following code sufficient?

```
freeReduce[] = []
freeReduce(x:xs) 
  | rest == []         = [x]
  | x == -(head rest)  = (tail rest)
  | otherwise          = (x:rest)
  where rest = freeReduce xs
```

Idea is that `rest` is always reduced as much as possible and thus the only way to get better is, to have a `x` before `rest` which cancels with the head of `rest` leaving the tail of `rest` as result.

*Edit:* added a line to handle an empty `rest`.

Comment: Also, you assume `rest` is not `[]`; when it is, you get an error.

Answer (score 5):

You could split it up in two separate functions, one that just checks if the first two elements of a the list cancel each other out, and another one that uses that to reduce the whole list.

```
-- check if the first two elements cancel each other
headReduce (x:y:zs) | x == -y = zs
headReduce xs = xs

-- build a whole reduced list from that
freeReduce []     = []
freeReduce (x:xs) = headReduce (x : freeReduce xs)
```

It works because if a list is completely reduced and you add another element in front, the only new possible reduction is that the first two elements now cancel each other out. Then per induction the result of `freeReduce` is always completely reduced.

Comment: I wish I could give another +1 for this simple, elegant solution.

Comment: Looks like same idea as @dave440's `foldr` solution.  Nice.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one liner, I hope it does cover all the cases as I haven't tested it much

```
freeReduce = foldr (\i a -> if a /= [] && i == -(hea­d a) then tail a else i:a ) []
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like homework, so I'm going to give a hint only.

You need to compare the first two items in the list, but also allow for lists with only one element or none, so your cases look like this:

```
  freeReduce (x1 : x2 : xs) = ....
  freeReduce [x] = [x]
  freeReduce [] = []
```

That covers all the cases.  So now you just need to decide what to do with the adjacent items x1 and x2, and how to feed this into the rest of the computation.

Answer (score 1):

Collecting already inspected elements in a backward list, and going "one step back" when we find a match:

```
freeReduce xs = reduce [] xs where
   reduce acc [] = reverse acc
   reduce [] (x:y:ys) | x == -y = reduce [] ys 
   reduce (a:as) (x:y:ys) | x == -y = reduce as (a:ys) 
   reduce acc (x:xs) = reduce (x:acc) xs
```